# Advance PowerPoint slides automatically

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm preparing for an Ignite talk and need to create a presentation in which each slide advances automatically after 15 seconds.

I'm using PowerPoint 2007 and there is a setting that supposedly does exactly this (Advance Slide Automatically After: ) but it does not work at all.  On every slide, I type 15 into the textbox and it shows 00:15.  But when I click Slide Show / From Beginning or Slide Show / From Current Slide it absolutely does not work.

Any suggestions?  Does anyone know of a PowerPoint template that has automatic advancing built in?

Comment: Which office version do you have?

Comment: PowerPoint 2007

Answer (score 6):

Well, judging by your question, you have Office 2007.

Try to follow these steps:

- Select all slides ("Home > Select > Select All" in the menu)
- Go to the "Animations" menu, tick "Automatically after" in "Advance slide" submenu, and enter 00:01 (for testing purposes, so that you wouldn't have to wait 15 seconds)
- Click "Slide Show > From Beginning"

Make sure that you do everything exactly as described. If it still won't work, then it is some kind of bug or configuration problem.

ED2: OK, some people had the same problem with powerpoint before. Here's [one solution](http://forums.techguy.org/all-other-software/574492-powerpoint-2003-slides-do-not.html). It's for PPT2003, but from what I've gathered "this is not a bug, it's a feature" :) So chances are that it's the same in next versions.

ED3: Yep, it seems that this is actually your problem. I've reproduced it on my presentation. If you have a single audio track you want to play across all slides, then this is what you have to do:

- Select that sound icon on your slide
- Go to "Animations" menu
- On the "Animations" submenu set "Animation:" option to "Play across slides"

If this is not your case (you have multiple audio files, or something else is different), then we'll try to find some other solution.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Doesn't work.

I do have audio and this may be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Are you running Power Point 2007?

I had this same problem, and every answer returned by google has something to do with music.  My slide show has NO music, only simple fade transitions and a 5 second delay (auto advance) applied to all slides in the standard way.  I kept digging, because there were NO answers on line about this.

Under "Slide Show">"Set Up Show" you will find some options that may or may not be clicked.  Two of them will kill your automatic advance.

One of them is under "Show Options".  Make sure "Show Without Animation" is NOT checked.

Next to that (to the right) is the "Advance Slides" Option.  Make sure "Use Timings, if Present" IS checked.

These two setting will override anything you set in Transitions and animations.

Answer (score 2):

You may have an embedded sound file. If so, do this:

1. Go to the first slide where you have the sound file embeded
2. Select **Animation**
3. Select **Custom Animation**
4. Click on the Sound icon inside the slide
5. On the right side of the screen, click on the pull-down menu for the sound object
6. Select **Effect** Option
7. Under the “Stop Playing: After”, enter `99`
8. Click **OK**

I don't know why it works but it works. It is the same solution for the previous version of Powerpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://inpics.net/tutorials/powerpoint2003/anim21.html):

> On the Menu Bar, click Edit, then
>   Select All. In the Slide Transition
>   pane, under Advance Slide, click the
>   Automatically after checkbox.

Comment: This is for PPT 2003, not 2007.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know. You did not mention that in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Following link may be of some help to you.
http://en.allexperts.com/q/Microsoft-PowerPoint-1035/Slide-transitions-sound.htm